# Show temporary "No items found" row in DataGridView if empty

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

How do I tell the DataGridView that if it is empty, it should automatically temporary add a new row inside and it's value should be "No items found"?

Using a message box could easily solve this one, but I don't like that method.

Here's my code

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection))
{
    string cell = dataGridView3.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
    conn.Open();
    string query = "SELECT product_item FROM dequor.prods2,dequor.prods where prods.idprods = prods2.prods_idprods and prod_brand=?para";
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?para", cell);
        try
        {
            sda2 = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            sda2.SelectCommand = cmd;
            datset2 = new DataTable();
            sda2.Fill(datset2);
            bsource2 = new BindingSource();


            bsource2.DataSource = datset2;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = bsource2;
            DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView2.Columns[0];
            column.Width = 125;
            sda2.Update(datset2);

            if (dataGridView2.RowCount < 1)
            {
                datset2.Clear();
                string row = "NO items found";
                dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row);
             //////got an error here
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Use of punctuation would make your question much easier to understand

Comment: ohh sorry for my mistake

Comment: "Got an error here" - you need to tell us what the error is. A compile error? Run time error? [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28050988/edit) to include this information.

Comment: "rows cannot be programatically added to the datagridviews row collection when control is data bound"..is there another way to add a row?

Comment: @grant tnx I've solve my problems with your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few options that I can think of.

1. Even if no records are returned, `datset2` should still have a single column in it called "product_item" after executing the query, so you could re-use that.

   ```
   datset2 = new DataTable();
   sda2.Fill(datset2);

   if (datset2.Rows.Count == 0)
   {
       // I'm assuming "product_item" is a string
       datset2.Rows.Add("No items found");
   }
   ```
2. You could instantiate a new `DataTable`, and add the column you want in it, and use that. I don't really see a point to that, but it's an option.

   ```
   if (datset2.Rows.Count == 0)
   {
       datset2 = new DataTable();
       datset2.Columns.Add("Message", typeof(string));
       datset2.Rows.Add("No items found");
   }
   ```
3. You could just add a `Label` to your `Form`, position it over the `DataGridView`, and hide it until it's necessary.

   ```
   labelNoDataMessage.Text = "No items found";

   if (datset2.Rows.Count == 0)
   {
       labelNoDataMessage.Show();
   }
   ```

Some third-party controls may have functionality built-in to support this, like Telerik's `RadGridView` and its [ShowNoDataText](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/p_telerik_wincontrols_ui_radgridviewelement_shownodatatext.html) property. The default `DataGridView` has no such property, however.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the answer from Grant Winney I ended up using this

```
 var dataTable = new DataTable();
 dataTable.Columns.Add("Message", typeof(string));
 dataTable.Rows.Add("No items found");

 myDataGridView.DataSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = dataTable };
 myDataGridView.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```